# KQL calculate the timespan of sequence

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a table with two columns `Ts` that represents datetime and `Index`. I want to calculate the total timespan of continuous sequence of indexes.

To do that, I used `scan` to calculate timespan:

```
let t = datatable(Ts: datetime, Index:int)
[
   datetime(2022-12-1), 1,
   datetime(2022-12-5), 2,
   datetime(2022-12-6), 3,
   datetime(2022-12-2), 10,
   datetime(2022-12-3), 11,
   datetime(2022-12-3), 12,
   datetime(2022-12-1), 18,
   datetime(2022-12-1), 19,
];
t
| sort by Index asc
| scan declare (startTime: datetime, index:int, totalTime: timespan) with 
(
    step inSession: true => startTime = iff(isnull(inSession.startTime), Ts, inSession.startTime), index = Index;
    step endSession: Index != inSession.index + 1 => totalTime = Ts - inSession.startTime;
)
```

But I get:

| Ts | Index | startTime | index | totalTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-01T00:00:00Z | 1 | 2022-12-01T00:00:00Z | 1 |  |
| 2022-12-05T00:00:00Z | 2 | 2022-12-01T00:00:00Z | 2 |  |
| 2022-12-06T00:00:00Z | 3 | 2022-12-01T00:00:00Z | 3 |  |
| 2022-12-02T00:00:00Z | 10 |  |  | 1.00:00:00 |
| 2022-12-02T00:00:00Z | 10 | 2022-12-02T00:00:00Z | 10 |  |
| 2022-12-03T00:00:00Z | 11 |  |  | 2.00:00:00 |
| 2022-12-03T00:00:00Z | 11 | 2022-12-02T00:00:00Z | 11 |  |
| 2022-12-03T00:00:00Z | 12 |  |  | 2.00:00:00 |
| 2022-12-03T00:00:00Z | 12 | 2022-12-02T00:00:00Z | 12 |  |
| 2022-12-01T00:00:00Z | 18 |  |  | -1.00:00:00 |
| 2022-12-01T00:00:00Z | 18 | 2022-12-01T00:00:00Z | 18 |  |
| 2022-12-01T00:00:00Z | 19 |  |  | 00:00:00 |
| 2022-12-01T00:00:00Z | 19 | 2022-12-01T00:00:00Z | 19 |  |

Instead (the desired result):

| Ts | Index | startTime | index | totalTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-01T00:00:00Z | 1 | 2022-12-01T00:00:00Z | 1 |  |
| 2022-12-05T00:00:00Z | 2 | 2022-12-01T00:00:00Z | 2 |  |
| 2022-12-06T00:00:00Z | 3 | 2022-12-01T00:00:00Z | 3 |  |
| 2022-12-02T00:00:00Z | 10 |  |  | 5.00:00:00 |
| 2022-12-02T00:00:00Z | 10 | 2022-12-02T00:00:00Z | 10 |  |
| 2022-12-03T00:00:00Z | 11 | 2022-12-02T00:00:00Z | 11 |  |
| 2022-12-03T00:00:00Z | 12 | 2022-12-02T00:00:00Z | 12 |  |
| 2022-12-01T00:00:00Z | 18 |  |  | 1.00:00:00 |
| 2022-12-01T00:00:00Z | 18 | 2022-12-01T00:00:00Z | 18 |  |
| 2022-12-01T00:00:00Z | 19 | 2022-12-01T00:00:00Z | 19 |  |
| 2022-12-01T00:00:00Z | 19 |  |  | 00:00:00 |

What is wrong with my query? How can I get the desired result?

Comment: This required results format does not seem to make any sense

Comment: You are right, I paste table from previous experiment, instead of 17 it should be 18. But anyway, I need the `5.00:00:00`, `1.00:00:00`, `00:00:00`

Comment: Not only the data but also the format itself - the combination between the original rows and these summarization rows in the same result set.

Comment: Hmm, I see. I'm new to KQL, and I took an example from the official documentation. I thought that's the way it summarizes with `scan`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let t = datatable(Ts: datetime, Index:int)
[
   datetime(2022-12-1), 1,
   datetime(2022-12-5), 2,
   datetime(2022-12-6), 3,
   datetime(2022-12-2), 10,
   datetime(2022-12-3), 11,
   datetime(2022-12-3), 12,
   datetime(2022-12-1), 18,
   datetime(2022-12-1), 19,
];
t
| sort by Index asc
| summarize rows = count(), min(Ts), max(Ts), min(Index), max(Index) by group_id = Index - row_number()
| extend totalTime = max_Ts - min_Ts
| project-away group_id
| order by min_Index asc
```

| rows | min_Ts | max_Ts | min_Index | max_Index | totalTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2022-12-01T00:00:00Z | 2022-12-06T00:00:00Z | 1 | 3 | 5.00:00:00 |
| 3 | 2022-12-02T00:00:00Z | 2022-12-03T00:00:00Z | 10 | 12 | 1.00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2022-12-01T00:00:00Z | 2022-12-01T00:00:00Z | 18 | 19 | 00:00:00 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA32QwWrDMAyG734KHRNIoHVp2Vr2ALvnNkpwYjE8YrvYCs3KHn5SUrpLOuyDrE/6f1kDEhC8gTXEpxuwaPJRXkjOYwXvweJ0dIFK9aEAHqTQG63rLd+ygm21ivaM9Do6MNqtIy2Cm3W2E/bEbWZP7OYhX/5hr5U6nxSpH8gxEXTfy8fB5F5yo/cmuRtCitfM2+rjGKjgRu8CL0wCM90Dzsy99+QSi+JniuOldZb7F/Fa5Now+g5TUbIPToTBAkUyQ8MzciVLtE3mUtblgIsuKX5hT7W5mj9NzsdkMYmPVD6m/wWRXmYF4AEAAA==)